# Wordpress como eu posso criar vários loops na index?

Tags: wordpress, loop

Eu estou tentando criar varios loops na minha index no wordpress , queria chamar os posts da seguinte forma:

Lançamentos: mostrando apenas 6 posts.
Séries: Mostrando apenas 6 posts.
Filmes Recentes: Mostrando apenas 6 posts porem com paginação.

já tentei e conseguir porem a paginação não funciona muito bem quando vai pra pagina 2 eu queria q mostrasse apenas os últimos posts mais ela faz paginação nos Lançamentos e nas Séries tmb.

Resumindo eu queria uma index igual desse site: efilmesnarede.com

Comment: Na index do site de exemplo me parece apenas um link para a /page/2, sendo a index uma index custom e a /page/2 uma página de archive com paginação. Em tese: Index = uma página com os 3 loopings e a /page/2 = uma pagina de arquivo com apenas um looping dos filmes mais recentes e com paginação.

Answer (score 0):

É simples, para isso o Wordpress tem o filtro array do `while( have_posts( ) )`
Vou por aqui como deve ser o código, dei uma comentada nele para lhe mostrar:

```
<?php
$args = array('showposts'  => 5,  # Quantidade de Posts a serem Mostrados, use -1 para puxar todos!
              'post_status' => 'publish', # PEGA APENAS POSTAGENS PUBLICADAS.
              'category_name' => 'lancamentos'; # PEGA OS POSTS PELA CATEGORIA.
            );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); # PEGA OS ARGUMENTOS SETADO ACIMA!

    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); # VERIFICA SE TEM POSTAGENS.
?>

       CÓDIGO QUE DEVE SER REPETIDO FICA AQUI! 

<?php endwhile; endif; # FIM DA VERIFICAÇÃO DE POSTAGENS. # CASO QUEIRA, USE UM ELSE: NO WHILE FICANDO ELSE: ENDWHILE; ENDIF; E NO ELSE COLOQUE O CODIGO 404.
wp_reset_query(); # RESETA O QUERY PARA NÃO TER CONFLITO NOS PRÓXIMO LOOPS ABAIXO ?>
```

Boa sorte no seu sistema!